# How to add assemblies in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, mapxtreme

I am using mapxtreme in asp.net application. Now in another application of Asp.net Core 2 , I wanT to use the mapxtreme. But not know how to add assemblies and mapxtreme setting in my ASP.NET CORE web project.

Find attached screenshot of web.config of asp.net application (see appSettings and assemblies section).I want to use the same settings in ASP.NET CORE 2 Web Project. Any Idea where to add this in ASP.NET CORE WEB Project ?

[image: ASP.NET WEB.CONFIG FILE SHOWING ENTRIES FOR MAPXTREME]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net Core does not support web.config. Following are few steps to add the reference in Asp.Net Core in your case

1. You have to move appSettings section from web.config to appsettings.json. You can read more about it at [MicroSoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration)
2. If mapxtreme is available as nuget package then install it from nuget package. Otherwise create a folder called as third party, copy mapextreme dlls into third party folder and a add reference of these libraries from third party folder. **But important thing is mapextreme libraries should be compliant with .NetStandard 2.0**.